# Commutator question

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, operators, commutator, vector-fields

I'm watching this video going through a non-rigorous explanation of the Einstein field equations:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foRPKAKZWx8

At around [1:17:50](https://youtu.be/foRPKAKZWx8?t=1h17m50s) he shows an identity involving the commutator of what looks like the differential operator and a function of $x$. This is what I don't understand. It looks weird to begin with, having just the operator there instead of an actual derivative of a function. He then comes up with the variable $v$ so that there is something to apply the operator to. On the left hand side he writes $v$ to the right and then says that there is now a derivative of a product. But how is that? If the differential operator is applied to $v$, why is the left hand side not the derivative of $v$ multiplied by the function $f(x)$? And why this commutator does not immediately equal zero, since we are (I believe) dealing with normal multiplication which is commutative? Then at the end he simply crosses the $v$ out without further explanation than saying it's something that he invented for the purpose of having something to apply the differential operator to.

Could somebody clarify to me exactly what he is doing here? Specifically between [1:17:50](https://youtu.be/foRPKAKZWx8?t=1h17m50s) and 1:20:20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the commutator $\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} , f(x) \right]$ involves a derivative, you might think that its action on some function $v(x)$ would depend on the derivative of $v(x)$. However, it turns out, as the proof in the video shows, that it acts purely multiplicatively, simply multiplying $v(x)$ by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

Furthermore, since the action of this commutator doesn't depend on $v(x)$, we can **identify** this particular commutator with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. That is, for any possible function $v(x)$, acting with the commutator and multiplying by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ give the same result. This is what we mean when we write $\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} , f(x) \right] = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ without including the function $v(x)$, even though strictly speaking the equality only holds when acting on some function.

## Edit 1

Here I will prove the particular commutator identity in the video.

**Claim:** For any function $v(x)$, we have $\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} , f(x) \right] v(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} v(x)$.

**Proof:** In physics we tend to use the convention that derivative operators operate on everything to the *right* of them. With this in mind, let's expand out the commutator.

$$\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} , f(x) \right] v(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( f(x) v(x) \right) - f(x) \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}. $$

Notice that, with our convention of right-acting derivatives, the first term has the derivative acting on a product, but in the second term it only acts on $v(x)$. It is for this reason that the commutator is not zero. This is also why we need to consider the *action* of the commutator on some 'test' function, because only in this case does the product rule behaviour of the derivative come into play.

To continue, we can use the product rule on the first term to give

$$\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} , f(x) \right] v(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} v(x) + f(x) \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - f(x) \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}. $$

The last two terms cancel, and we are left with

$$\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} , f(x) \right] v(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} v(x)$$

for **any** choice of the function $v(x)$. As I mentioned in my original post, because this behaviour doesn't depend on the choice of $v(x)$, it is common to write the commutator identity *without* $v(x)$, even though, as the proof shows, we need to consider the action of the commutator on some function for this identity to be valid.

## Edit 2

First some general review. Consider two operators, $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$. Their product $\hat{A}\hat{B}$ is also an operator, whose action is equivalent to acting with $\hat{B}$ and then on the result of that with $\hat{A}$. A similar statement holds for $\hat{B}\hat{A}$. It follows that the commutator $[\hat{A},\hat{B}] = \hat{A}\hat{B} - \hat{B}\hat{A}$ is *also an operator*, whose action is equivalent to acting with $\hat{A}\hat{B}$ and subtracting from that the action of $\hat{B}\hat{A}$.

Now let's consider an example. Let $\hat{A} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. That is, $\hat{A}$ is an operator whose action is to take the derivative of whatever it acts upon. Note also that operators act on everything to their **right**, which connects with what I said earlier about derivatives acting on everything to their right. So, for example, $\hat{A} v(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} v(x)$, and $\hat{A} (f(x) v(x)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} ( f(x) v(x) ) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} v(x) + f(x) \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.

Next let's set $\hat{B} = f(x)$. That is, $\hat{B}$ is an operator whose action is simply to multiply whatever it acts upon by $f(x)$. So, for example, $\hat{B} v(x) = f(x) v(x)$.

Now let's consider the action of the commutator on $v(x)$. Keeping the $\hat{A}$, $\hat{B}$ notation for clarity, this gives

$$[\hat{A}, \hat{B}]v(x) = \hat{A}\hat{B}v(x) - \hat{B}\hat{A}v(x).$$

Let's consider the two terms separately. Recall that in the definition of the action of the product $\hat{A}\hat{B}$, we have to act with $\hat{B}$ first. With $\hat{B} = f(x)$, we have $\hat{B} v(x) = f(x) v(x)$. Then we act with $\hat{A}$ on the result of this action. Since the result of the action of $\hat{B}$ is the product $f(x) v(x)$, we act with $\hat{A}$ on this product. With $\hat{A} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, this means that

$$\hat{A}\hat{B} v(x) = \hat{A} ( f(x) v(x) ) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} ( f(x) v(x) ).$$

Thus, we can see that in the first term of the action of the commutator, a derivative acts on the product $f(x) v(x)$.

Comment: Yes, if you could please go through the proof I would be grateful. I still can't understand how the operator acts multiplicatively. I tried to naively work out examples on paper by choosing some functions but I always just apply the operator to the function and therefore I get zero.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand at all how the operator acts on the product instead of just the function v. How can it do that? I thought that the commutator is simply the first term inside the brackets times the second term, minus the second term times the first term. I just can't see how the function f gets inside the derivative when it should be just multiplying the derivative of v.

Comment: Oh, now I got it! Earlier I kept thinking about just functions and their derivatives but I failed to see that the commutator is really about operators. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped!